# Could incorporating locks degrade performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, locking, locks

I have to write an ETL program for event data which loads events into Kafka, so in loader call I get an array of events. Inside loader I need to look at each event and based on certain parameters I need to decide its category which has a one-to-one mapping with some Kafka topic, where it should be written. They are not more than 20 Kafka topic to write to.

So my doubt is whether I should cache topics seen in a map as below: (Lets assume that I have started a no. of threads to divide the events among them and try loading into Kafka in parallel)

```
    class Loader {
      private static Map<String, String> eventCategoryVsKafkaTopic = new HashMap<String, String>();
      ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

      public static void load(IEvent[] events) {
        for(IEvent[] event) {
        String eventCategory = getEventCategory(event);
        lock.readLock().lock();
        if(eventCategoryVsKafkaTopic.get(eventCategory) != null) {
          loadToKafka(event, eventCategoryVsKafkaTopic.get(eventCategory));
        }
        lock.readLock().unlock();
        String kafkaTopic = generateKafkaTopicFromEvent(event);
        loadToKafka(event, kafkaTopic);
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        eventCategoryVsKafkaTopic.put(eventCategory, kafkaTopic); // Its fine, if some other thread has written it in between, as the topic will be the same so overwrite is not an issue
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
      }
    }
}
```

I feel this much of locking would be an overkill and may degrade performance rather if I just create topic on the fly every time as below: (Again assume that I have started a no. of threads and distributed events among them to load in parallel)

```
 class Loader {

      public static void load(IEvent[] events) {
        for(IEvent[] event) {
        String kafkaTopic = generateKafkaTopicFromEvent(event);
        loadToKafka(event, kafkaTopic);
      }
    }
}
```

Please suggest which one is the better way to handle topic generation and is involving locks a good idea here.

Comment: How much work is involved in generating the kafka topic? If it takes a lot of resources and you need to avoid doing it repeatedly, but don't want to use locks, then make the hash map local to each thread. Best of both worlds.

Comment: Not much I feel, it is just appending some 3-4 properties with a field inside event (eventCategory), but just thinking if it could be big when done thousands of events.

Comment: Using local HashMaps is a good idea btw. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Having all threads compete for one lock for every processed event will probably be slower. Without knowing more, generating a topic name is probably really quick.

Long answer:
If possible, try and build concurrent applications where threads communicate as little as possible. Sharing state like this across all working threads is going to create a lot of contention.

If generating that topic takes a lot of time then caching it is a good idea. However if there are only 20 topics then you should cache it locally to each thread to avoid each thread competing for the same lock for every event being processed.

A basic model would be to separate consumers and producers by some concurrent queue. Have consumers run in their own thread but share no state with other consumers. Consumers can cache the mappings locally if they need to.